# How can I remove vertical spacing around a centered element?

Tags: xetex, mla-style

I have a paper that uses the package `mla13`. It starts like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvips,xetex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{mla13}
\firstname{Jonathan}
\lastname{Reeve}
\professor{Writing Sample}
\class{Submitted with Graduate Application}
\title{Narrative Chiaroscuro: Light and Dark Imagery in \emph{Bleak House} and \emph{Middlemarch}} 
\begin{document}
\makeheader 
In an 1873 review in the \emph{Galaxy}, Henry James criticizes George Eliot's \emph{Middlemarch} as he might a painting:
```

A look at `mla13.sty` shows that this is all that's going on to produce the header and title:

```
\newcommand*{\makeheader}{\begingroup
\rmfamily
\fontsize{12}{2}
\noindent \@firstname\ \@lastname\\
\@professor\\
\@class\\
\datef\@date
\begin{center}
\@title
\end{center}
\endgroup}
```

But what I'm getting is this:

[image: screenshot]

With vertical space around the title. According to MLA specifications, there shouldn't be additional space above and below the title. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 5):

Replace `\begin{center}` by `{\centering` and `\end{center}` by `\par}` to lose the vertical spaceing.

```
\fontsize{12}{2}
```

means 12pt font with 2pt baseline, do you intend that?

Comment: I don't actually know what 2pt baseline is. I think that just came in the `mla13` package.

Comment: @Jon it specifies that the characters are 12pt tall but the distance between lines of text in a paragraph is 2pt. Tex will find this hard!!!!! to do and produce inconsistent line spacing

Comment: Replacing `\begin{center}` by `{\centering` and `\end{center}` by `\par}` has the nasty side-effect of centering the previous three lines in the header. But incidentally, it does remove the spacing.

Comment: @Jon -- Try `{\par\centering <your text goes here\par}`