# Flushleft vs raggedright and line ending in linguistic examples

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-spacing, linguistics, vertical-spacing, linguex

(**Note**: this is related to [How to fix spacing with multi-line cgloss4e examples?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440218/how-to-fix-spacing-with-multi-line-cgloss4e-examples))

I am trying to typeset linguistic examples with LaTeX, and in an a5 page setup. I am using linguex and cgloss4e. I need sometimes to input a first line that is not part of the example, which adds some space between the first line and the example (2nd line) & the gloss (3rd line), and also between the gloss and the translation (4th line). The addition of space is caused by **flushleft**, which is doing the alignment under the hood. (In order to see the results, comment out the part between **makeatletter** and **makeatother**; somehow I can't upload a screenshot to the page)

One workaround for the problem is to replace the flushleft environment by **raggedright**, as done in the patches between . However, this sometimes causes problems in that the line-ending is no longer correctly dealt with: the example does not respect the margin, and even goes beyond the page – which is not an issue with flushleft.

Is there a way of getting the same vertical space as with flushleft, and the same horizontal space as with raggedright, while continuing to use linguex?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{geometry}%
\geometry{headsep=3mm,includehead,margin=10mm,nofoot}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{linguex,cgloss4e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% patches - comment out to see behavior with pure cgloss4e
\makeatletter% Group everything to save the trouble
\patchcmd{\gll}% The command to be patched
  {\begin{flushleft}}% Code to be replaced
  {\begingroup\raggedright}% New code
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\gl@stop}% The command to be patched
  {\end{flushleft}}% Code to be replaced
  {\endgroup}% New code
  {}{}
\makeatother
%%% end patches
\begin{document}

\blindtext{}

\ex. Meaningless example from Language
\gll Kono kuruma-wa takai  takai-koto-wa takai-desu-ka?\\ 
This car-\textsc{top} expensive expensive-\textsc{nmlz}-\textsc{cont} expensive-\textsc{pred}.\textsc{polite}-Q\\
`Is this car expensive?'

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74058063/linguistic-examples-gloss-and-flushleft-vs-raggedright

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215555/how-can-i-remove-vertical-spacing-around-a-centered-element See my comment to your original post for a more detailed explanation of why this is a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `\par` in order to finish up the work of `\raggedright`. I also add `\addvspace{\topsep}` to get the same vertical spacing at the end as for `flushleft`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=3mm,includehead,margin=10mm,nofoot}

\usepackage{linguex,cgloss4e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% patches - comment out to see behavior with pure cgloss4e
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\gll}% The command to be patched
  {\begin{flushleft}}% Code to be replaced
  {\begingroup\raggedright}% New code
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\gl@stop}% The command to be patched
  {\end{flushleft}}% Code to be replaced
  {\par\addvspace{\topsep}\endgroup}% New code
  {}{}
\makeatother
%%% end patches
\begin{document}

\ex. Meaningless example from Language
\gll Kono kuruma-wa takai  takai-koto-wa takai-desu-ka?\\
This car-\textsc{top} expensive expensive-\textsc{nmlz}-\textsc{cont}
expensive-\textsc{pred}.\textsc{polite}-Q\\
`Is this car expensive?'

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as needed!